# i have just started coding in android my ques. is how to pass edittext data by the help of button in textview in same activity

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
    <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editView"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:text="Click"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

i am not getting how to code please give some solution 
i want that what i write in editveiw will show on textview when i click on button in same activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); 
        Edittext myTextButton = (Edittext) findViewById(R.id.editView);
        myTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            }
        }
```

Comment: u r missing  setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); 
after 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: First your code has a problem you have `Editview` instead of` EditText`???

Comment: Yes also `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);` edit your question and you will get an answer. Just edit!

Answer (score 2):

**Please check Below Code**

```
     final TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
     final EditText editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editView);
     Button button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```